# What's this type of leak detection method called?

Tags: data-leakage

Suppose I want to figure out which of a group of people is distributing my content without authorization.  So I create several different versions of the same content, each with a unique watermark embedded.  Then, when I come across a pirate copy of the content in the wild, I can check the watermark, so I can see which of the original recipients was the distributor.

What is this method of leak detection called?

Comment: Figured it out--it's a "canary trap".

Comment: Ha, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the term you're looking for is a ["canary trap"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_trap), which is a form of [offensive counterintelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterintelligence#Offensive_counterintelligence_operations).

This is similar to a suspected double-agent being given false information, which they then leak back to their handlers. This can then be used to show that the agent, being the only one told that information, was the real leak.